# How to pull data out of dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to basically create an `if` statement that is able to find out how many goals are scored in the first half of a soccer match that Barcelona played in. The stats are all there with the number beside then representing the minute the goal was scored in. So how would I write my `if` statement like that. I know how to do it with a simple variable with just a single value like either a string or a number but how would I find a value in a dictionary with a specific number value and the specific number value I want?

```
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [[String : Int]]()  // if you want this globally
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal":21,"RealMadridGoal":23]
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1penaltys  : [String : Int] = ["RealMadridPenalty":21,"barcelonaPenalty":23]


if barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals == ["barcelonaGoal":21] {
        print("Fond it")
    }
```

Comment: Like for instance. print all goals that are from the Barcelona match and are greater the the initial value of 1000

Comment: I cannot make any sense of your "data structure" at all. And "IF" is a branching control construct, not something to pull data out of dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve data in dictionaries easily:

```
barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals["barcelonaGoal"]
```

But I have to tell you that I think your data structure will not work the way you want it to. For example, you can't put several goals for one team into the dictionary.

Build classes for your data and encapsulate properly. Don't throw "everything in something" and build on some magic element names. Understand the concepts you are using.

I think reading a good programming introduction might be called for, and then the Swift programming guide comes into mind.

**Edit**

Here's a **very** simplified example of what a game data structure could look like:

```
class Game {
    var team1 : String
    var team2 : String

    var minutesOfGoalsTeam1: [Int]
    var minutesOfGoalsTeam2: [Int]

    init(team1 t1 : String, team2 t2: String) {
        team1 = t1
        team2 = t2
        minutesOfGoalsTeam1 = []
        minutesOfGoalsTeam2 = []
    }

    func goalsTeam1() -> Int {
        return minutesOfGoalsTeam1.count
    }

    func goalsTeam2() -> Int {
        return minutesOfGoalsTeam2.count
    }

    func addGoal(team : String, minute : Int) {
        if team == team1 {
            minutesOfGoalsTeam1.append(minute)
        }
        if team == team2 {
            minutesOfGoalsTeam2.append(minute)
        }
    }

    func winner() -> String {
        if goalsTeam1() > goalsTeam2() {
            return team1
        }
        if goalsTeam2() > goalsTeam1() {
            return team2
        }
        return "DRAW"
    }
}

let game = Game(team1: "Barcelona", team2: "Madrid")
game.addGoal("Barcelona", minute: 5)
game.winner()
```

Adding penalties is left as an exercise. This is really just the tip of the ice berg. There are hundreds of ways to do it, and I wouldn't consider this the best approach. For example, one could think about a dedicated team class. Or using some game event class with subclasses for goals and penalties, and adding those to an array and looping over it for the concrete data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var goalCount=0
for (goal,numbers) in barcelonavsRealMadrid1{
for(var number in numbers){
if(number < 45)
    goalCount++

  }
}
```

i think it will work

Comment: Swift 2 doesn't read it very well but it looks like it just needs a minor adjustments